# Aspect fill the image according to the size of image

Tags: html, css, image

i have alot of images in a database which has completely different dimensions. i want to make sure that these images have the cut these images so they have same size and still aspect ratio.

so depending on the size i want to do something like this where the div is the wanted size and the image is cut off if it does not fit the size of the div. illustration

[image]

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-family:"Helvetica Neue UltraLight",helvetica,verdana;
            margin-left:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-top: 0;
            width   100%;
        }
        section{
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        h1{
            font-size: 16px;
            padding-left:5px;
        }
        .main_image {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .main_image img{

             width: auto;
             height:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="main_image">
       <img src="[[[main_image]]]" alt="" />
   </div>
   <h1>[[[title]]]</h1>
   <section>
        <p>[[[full_text]]]</p>
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image as the background of the container, and set its size to cover:

```
<div class="main_image" style="background-image:url([[[main_image]]])" title="[[[alt_desc]]]"></div>

.main_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will scale the image proportionally to fill the container and "crop" out the excess.

Comment: True, but you can set a `title` attribute on the container DIV to get the same effect -- accessibility description and tooltip on hover.  I edited the answer above to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Should be relatively straightforward to centre it horizontally and vertically.

```
    .main_image img{
         width: auto;
         height: auto;
         margin: auto;
    }
```